# Xamarin.iOS multiple asset catalogs

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio, asset-catalog

With the newest Xamarin Studio (4.0.13) I'm trying to use asset catalogs in my app. The app has **two** different app icon sets: one for all test (Test.plist) and staging (Staging.plist) builds, and one for all pre-production (PreProduction.plist) and Production (Production.plist) builds. The test bundle contains NO app icons, since we want QA to be clear this is NOT the same as a production build.

I've already started doing a Pre-Build plist `cp` step (not ideal; Xamarin Studio should support conditionally including files based on build config). Is there a way to conditionally bundle (build action `ImageAsset`) the `.appiconset` and `.launchimage` specific to my build configuration? I've specified the relevant `XSAppIconAssets` and `XSLaunchImageAssets`, but since they're all marked `ImageAsset` they all get copied in anyway, and (unfortunately) copied into the root folder where Springboard can find and display them.

Is there any way around this without:

- Adding yet more Pre-Build `cp`ing to bundle the correct icon sets into one set which is the only one marked `ImageAsset`:

  ```
  cp iPhone/buildPlists/Staging-Info.plist Info.plist;
  cp -r Resources/Images.xcassets/TestAppIcons.appiconset/*
        Resources/Images.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset;
  cp -r Resources/Images.xcassets/TestLaunchImages.launchimage/*
        Resources/Images.xcassets/LaunchImages.launchimage
  ```
- <s>Adding blank image files to the `TestAppIcons.appiconset` catalog?</s> *This doesn't work, the order icon sets are copied to the output folder is undefined*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the above `cp` script which has essentially solved my problem.

More information which may help others:

You can't rely on `XSAppIconAssets` and `XSLaunchImageAssets` being checked AFTER you do a Pre-Build plist copy step. Xamarin Studio appears to use the values present in `Info.plist` at the *beginning* of the build process.

Asset catalogs work the following way under the hood:

- In general, catalog images are copied into the `.app` in the form `CatalognameModifiers.ext` (e.g. `LaunchImages@2x.png`)

  - For Launch Images, the catalog name is assigned to the `UILaunchImages` key in `Info.plist`, and the OS handles the lookup of these transparently
  - For App Icons, the Icons are renamed to `CatalognameDimensions.ext`, including the `57x57` (which previously were simply `Icon.png`/`Icon@2x.png`), and these names are assigned to arrays under the `CFBundleIcons` and `CFBundleIcons~ipad` keys in `Info.plist`

As a result of the above renaming, you need to specify the **catalog name**, not the 'asset name' as mentioned [here](http://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-studio-and-ios-7/). In my case, I was puzzled over launch images suddenly not appearing in the app (my app moves from a splash screen to a loading spinner over the splash image). The solution was changing the code to request `UIImage.FromBundle("LaunchImages")`, rather than `"Default"`. Note that for iPhone 5 you currently need to request `"LaunchImages-568h"` to get the right image.